# FreeBSD: RAID driver issue

Tags: freebsd, raid

Is it possible to compile two versions of RAID drivers ([`aac`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=aac&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)) for the FreeBSD kernel, and load whichever required based on hardware in `loader.conf` later?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did.

Added both new version and old version of aac to compiled ISO.

I tried to load both drivers on my new hardware, given different name(aac_new) for new version of aac driver and kernel internally managed to use this new version.

Loaded only old version on old hardware using loader.conf by disabling aac_new.